# How do interfaces work with in a VPN (en 0 & tun 0)

Tags: vpn

VPN noobie here with a general VPN question.

I have just installed a vpn on my mac. When i opened wireshark to check what was going on in the VPN i notice that two interfaces are at work. One interface (en0) is my wifi connection to the router set up in the house and the other interface (tun0), which has a new IP to it and I'm assuming is a tunnel

How are these interfaces playing with each other? 
Is one (en0) going through the other (tun0) and back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tun0` would be the VPN interface. However, the VPN is only a virtual interface. The traffic must travel over a physical interface to communicate with the internet. So all traffic traveling over `tun0` must travel over a physical interface such as `en0`, albeit in a likely encrypted state.

Comment: So basically you're tunnelling through the virtual interface (tun0) (i.e packet in a packet) and sending it over the physical interface (en0). Correct?

Comment: @LightAlchemist Yep!